# What changed in event handling with Backbone.Marionette 1.0.0-beta1?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-events

I just tried the new Marionette 1.0.0-beta with my existing project. After fiddling around with it for many hours, I must say the altered event handling confuses me.

- Events seem to fire doubled. May be an artifact of the new triggerMethod() call?
- Event bubbling in CollectionViews doesn't seem to work for standard events like 'item:rendered'. Those fire inside the ItemViews, but not the parent CollectionView. Is this intended?
- What are the different event handling methods are meant to be used for? EventAggregator, EventBinder, Wreqr, native Backbone Events, …?

Would be great, if you could clear things up. It would also be great, if you could mark the existing documentation as being appropriate for what versions of Marionette.

Comment: I didn't notice all the problems you reported with events, just a few minor issue with composite views. Anyway it's just a beta so I think the documentation will be updated as the final versione will be released.

Comment: Can you re-post this in the Marionette issues on Github? https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues thanks.

Comment: Actually I'm noticing now that with 1.0.0 beta1 render() is called twice on CompositeView first render, didn't happen with 0.10.2...

Comment: ingro - can you log that as a bug in the issue list?

Comment: Filed as issues #288 (docs) and #289 (events doubled). Event bubbling seems to already exist as #281.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the event bubbling in CollectionViews, there is a [pull request](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/pull/281) to fix this as it is a bug